# How to find end of each "wave" in BFS?

Tags: c++, graph, iterator, breadth-first-search

I have a Node in Graph:

```
struct Node {
    std::string value;
    Id id;
    std::vector<Node*> neighbours;
}
```

and I've made graph iterator to do BFS (overridden map iterator). I need to find distance between two values (which will BFS do) but I'm not sure how to write a function. The main problem is how to check whether one "wave" is over. So for the first "wave" I could check if number of iterations is equal to number of neighbours and that would do it, but for second "wave" and others I have no idea what to do. I started writing a function like this:

```
int find_level_of_acquaintance(const std::string& user1, const std::string& user2) {
    int level = 0;
    auto iter1 = nodes.find(user1); // nodes is map, and this iterator is start point
    // implementation 
    // when each wave is over I would level++, but how can I know when it's over?
}
```

here's iterator implementation:

```
private:
std::set<Id> visited;
std::queue<Node*> to_visit;
Node* current_node;
public:
iterator& operator++() {
    for (Node* neighbour : current_node->neighbours) {
        if (!visited.contains(neighbour->id)) {
            visited.emplace(neighbour->id);
            to_visit.push(neighbour);
        }
    }
    visited.emplace(current_node->id);
    if (!to_visit.empty()) {
        current_node = to_visit.front();
        to_visit.pop();
    }
    else
        current_node = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

although I don't think I could change anything here, but make specific function.
My question is how to check when is one wave of search over?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an integer field to your `Node` struct called `generation`. When you add a node to the `std::queue`, set its `generation` to the current node's `generation` plus one. In the case of the root node, just set `generation` to zero. Set a global variable called `maxGeneration` to zero. At the start of processing each node, check if the current node's `generation` is greater than `maxGeneration`. If so, then a wave has completed and you should set `maxGeneration` to the current node's value. I solved this exact same problem in one of my projects.

I'm not an expert in modern C++, so here is a python implementation. Think of it as pseudocode.

```
from collections import deque

@dataclass
class Node:
    neighbors:list[int]
    generation: int

def bfs_waves(rootNode: Node, targetNode: Node):
    maxGeneration = 0
    rootNode.generation = 0
    Q=deque([rootNode])
    while len(Q) > 0:
        item = Q.popleft()
        if item is targetNode:
            print(f"Target Node Reached in {maxGeneration} steps.")
            return
        else:
            if item.generation > maxGeneration:
                printf(f"A wave has passed, generation {maxGeneration} is complete.")
                maxGeneration=item.generation
            for neighbor in item.neighbors:
                neighbor.generation=item.generation+1
                Q.append(neighbor)
    print("Target node could not be reached.")
```